# How to output json format errors in Golang rest, specifically referencing the bad fields

Tags: go, error-handling

I have the following requirement: return errors from a REST API in the following format:

```
Error format
422
{
    "name-of-field": [
        "can't be blank",
        "is too silly"
    ]
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
var PostFeedback = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    surveyId := params["id"]
    feedback := &models.Feedback{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(feedback)
    if err != nil {
        jsonError := fmt.Sprintf(`{
            "%s": [
                "%s"
            ]
        }`, "errors", err)
        log.Printf("invalid input format, %v", jsonError)
        resp := map[string]interface{}{"error": jsonError}
        u.Respond(w, resp)
        return
    }
```

**Questions:**

How do I get the names of the offending fields?
How do I satisfy the requirement best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package doesn't provide validation for "blank", nor "silly" values. It will return an error only if the data in the body is *not* a valid json, or if the field types in the json do not, according to the package's spec, match the field types of the structure into which you're trying to decode that json.

The 1st type of error would be the [`json.SyntaxError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#SyntaxError), if you get this it is not always possible to satisfy your requirements since there may be *no* actual fields which you could use in your response, or if there are json fields, they, and their values, may be perfectly valid json, but the cause of the error may lie elsewhere (see [example](https://play.golang.com/p/N3kTumeEN_2)).

In cases where the data holds actual json fields but it has, for example, non-json values you could use the `Offset` field of the `SyntaxError` type to find the closest preceding field in the data stream. Using [`strings.LastIndex`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#LastIndex) you can implement a *naive* solution to look backwards for the field.

```
data := []byte(`{"foobar": i'm not json}`)

err := json.Unmarshal(data, &T{})
se, ok := err.(*json.SyntaxError)
if !ok {
    panic(err)
}

field := string(data[:se.Offset])
if i := strings.LastIndex(field, `":`); i >= 0 {
    field = field[:i]
    if j := strings.LastIndex(field, `"`); j >= 0 {
        field = field[j+1:]
    }
}
fmt.Println(field) // outputs foobar
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.com/p/idxyW76oEWq)

*NOTE:* As you can see, for you to be able to look for the field, you need to have access to the data, but when you're using `json.NewDecoder` and passing it the request's body directly, without first storing its contents somewhere, you'll loose access to that data once the decoder's `Decode` method is done. This is because the body is a stream of bytes wrapped in a `io.ReadCloser` that does not support "rewinding", i.e. you cannot *re-read* bytes that the decoder already read. To avoid this you can use [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) to read the full contents of the body and then [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) to do the decoding.

---

The 2nd type of error would be the [`json.UnmarshalTypeError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#UnmarshalTypeError). If you look at the documentation of the error type and its fields you'll know that all you need to do is to type assert the returned value and you're done. [Example](https://play.golang.com/p/hJqNReYMGIm)

---

Validation against "blank" and "silly" values would be done after the json has been successfully decoded into your structure. How you do that is up to you. For example you could use a 3rd party package that's designed for validating structs, or you can implement an in-house solution yourself, etc. I actually don't have an opinion on which one of them is the "best" so I can't help you with that.

What I can say is that the most *basic* approach would be to simply look at each field of the structure and check if its value is valid or not according to the requirements for that field.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer.